# Checking acpi key bindings and remapping keyboard keypress events to acpi events

Tags: keyboard, suspend, remapping, events

I got two systems with Ubuntu 18.04.1 installed. The two have similar hardware and software configurations but one of them suspends to SBTN press event whereas the other does nothing. I checked gsettings and both have similar org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power configurations. I want to know the complete key bindings associated with SBTN key event.

How and where can I check for these?

Also, how can I remap a keyboard keypress event(say keycode 127 which is pause/break button) to SBTN button/PWBN button?

How can I map system suspend action to keyboard pause/break button?

PS: I'm using acpi_listen for listening to PWBN and SBTN key events and I'm able to see the key presses. For checking for keyboard events I'm using xinput test. Also, I need to get the system back live using the same keypress after suspend action.

Comment: Even though you may not be able to upvote an answer yet, please at least make a comment stating whether the solution I offered proved effective for future readers.

Comment: The solution offered doesn’t work. The system doesn’t wake up to keyboard or mouse inputs after some time though I’m able to login over ssh. Wondering if its a driver issue. I don’t even have any graphics card installed. It’s intel graphics 530 running on i915 driver.

Comment: Does it wake up (not reboot) when you short press the power button on your desktop/laptop?

Comment: Yes it wakes up doesn’t reboot. I’ve checked with open applications.

Comment: Ok in that case it is not a power issue, can you try these steps (they will temporarily enable power wakeup from all usb devices connected for this test):   
  `grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup > /home/dev_power_set.back && for line in $(cat /home/dev_power_set.back| cut -d ":" -f1); do echo enabled > $line;done `   and then type in `systemctl suspend` and test your various usb devices and see if you get any wakeup calls sent to the system.

Comment: My bad I missed this - The issue occurs only when the system is left for like 3-4hrs. If I suspend and wake it up immediately the screen comes up and things work fine even with a key press. I think it’s better if I open a different question on this issue. The one which I asked in this question is for a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the above approach is that the keyboard shortcuts created apply to the user in the session. I wanted the button assignment to be persistent across all users and didn't want any password to be entered for suspend to be executed.

Extending @BarBar1234's approach and settling with power button events rather than sleep button events, the following worked just fine though not the exact solution to the question posted.

```
$sudo vi /etc/acpi/events/power
event=button/power
action=/etc/acpi/suspendsys.sh

$sudo vi /etc/acpi/suspendsys.sh
#!/bin/bash
systemctl suspend

$sudo chmod u+x /etc/acpi/suspendsys.sh

$sudo systemctl restart acpid
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have acpi service running on the other machine, with `sudo systemctl status acpid` or `sudo service acpid status`

If you do, test `systemctl suspend` on the other machine that does not respond to the sleep/suspend button press and see if any errors or warnings get printed.

As far as setting a custom keybinding to Pause/Break key, I would try to bind it to a script that executes `systemctl suspend` command , as trying to remap sleep/suspend button will require clearing the previous binding for the built-in sleep/suspend key if there is one, if I recall correctly. In other words, make a script `suspendme.sh`.

```
touch suspendme.sh
nano suspendme.sh
```

inside the suspendme.sh script:

`#!/bin/bash
systemctl suspend`

```
chmod u+x suspendme.sh
mv suspendme.sh /usr/local/bin/
```

And then you can just use "System Settings" > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts" in both Gnome and Unity to set the shortcut. Just click on + and for the command to execute with the Pause key use `suspendme.sh` as it is in /usr/local/bin and will be part of the path.

Comment: How does the system wakeup? Will it search for script again when I press the sleep button when its in suspended state? I’m asking this since currently the system doesn’t respond to normal keyboard key button presses when suspended. It’s the bug I’m actually looking to circumvent.

Comment: check `grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup` and change the listen to wake up with `echo enabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup`  change usb1 to the the path of your keyboard.

Comment: Once you find the correct usb path of your keyboard and successfully test it, make sure you make it permanent, by pasting the `echo enabled > [sys bus path to keyboard]` into  /etc/rc.local. You will likely need to sudo, so `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` and paste it there.

Comment: It should be _chmod_ not _chown_.